# MySQL - Order by values in separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have two MySQL tables. 
Table1:

```
id name otherid
```

Table2:

```
id otherid time
```

In each table, the "id" is a unique identifier for every row (and is also the primary key)
the "otherids" correspond between tables. There may be several (or 0) rows in table2 that have an otherid that corresponds to an otherid in table1. Table

For example,
Table 1:

```
id name otherid
1  bob  24
2  joe  326
```

Table 2:

```
id otherid time
4  326     2014-03-12 023:38:59
5  24      2013-02-11 22:05:21
6  24      2013-02-10 13:27:58
```

I am looking to fetch every row in table1, ordered by the most recent time of the rows in table2 that go with it according to the otherid.
In my example, this is the result I would be looking for:

```
id name time
2  joe  2014-03-12 023:38:59
1  bob  2013-02-11 22:05:21
```

This is because Joe has the most recent time from table2.

Comment: I've tried multiple queries but didn't save them, but most recently: SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.time FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.otherid = table2.otherid ORDER BY table2.time

Comment: Do you need to fetch records from table1 if there are no corresponding rows in table2?

Comment: That is not required, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below example :

```
SELECT table1.*, max(table2.time) 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.otherid = table2.otherid
GROUP BY table2.otherid
ORDER BY table2.id
```

See [SqlFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81716/3)

Comment: Looking at the SQL fiddle, it doesn't seem to order by the time. However, changing the last line to ORDER BY table2.timing DESC seems to do the trick. Let me do some more testing

Comment: No ORDER BY should not matter  as long as you are GROUPING and fetching the time value using MAX function, it will always retrieve maximum date-time value, If you are looking for also sorting based on maximum timing then YES you can use ORDER BY time, updated SqlFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT MIN(a.id) AS `id`, MIN(a.name) AS `name`, MAX(b.time) AS `time`
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b ON a.otherid = b.otherid
GROUP BY a.otherid
ORDER BY b.time DESC
```

Working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/915cb/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MAX` function for get most recent time.

ex. `MAX(time)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Table1.id, name, MAX(time)
FROM
    Table1
    JOIN Table2 USING (otherid)
GROUP BY
    otherid
ORDER BY
    time DESC
```

Comment: `id` column are redundant.we must use table alias here?

Comment: is there any changes if i use `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @diEcho if you use `INNER JOIN` you can either put `USING (otherid)` or `ON (Table1.otherid = Table2.otherid)`, but in the latter case you will have to specify a table to group by

Comment: why you have changed the code? earlier code was looking  different and interesting

Comment: @diEcho I changed it based on your comments; there was an ambiguity in the `id` column, so `NATURAL JOIN` would try to incorrectly join on both `id` and `otherid` at the same time which is wrong (unless that column actually has a different name in your real schema).  Per @OMGPonies, `DISTINCT` is not needed.  I wrote it because originally I wasn't using `GROUP BY`, but I forgot to remove it when I did.

Comment: @diEcho: NATURAL JOIN is ANSI, but not recommended because it chooses the JOIN criteria for you -- the issue is that it might not be consistent.

Comment: `USING` is also not recommended to use, beginning with **MySQL 5.0.12**, Read [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)  : 
Transformation of `NATURAL` or `USING` joins into `JOIN ... ON`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(table1.id),table1.name,table2.time FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.otherid=table2.otherid
ORDER BY table2.time DESC;
```

Comment: That PostgreSQL syntax, not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with a join and subquery:

```
select id, name
from tb1 a
left join
(select otherid, max(dt) mdt
from tb2
group by otherid) b
on a.otherid = b.otherid
order by b.mdt desc
;
```