# MySql Data Merge

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display a specific set of data. My problem is that part of the data is in a different table, same db. So this is what I have:

Two tables. T1 has 5 columns. T2 has 8 columns. FormId column is common between the two tables. I need to move DateSubmitted column from T1 to T2 and then run `SELECT` query on resulting combined columns. So far I am only have a working `SELECT` query for T2. I cannot figure out how to move DateSubmitted column from T1 to T2 and then run `SELECT` query. I tried `UNION` and `JOIN` suggestions I found here and on other forums but without success. Need help with constructing working query please!

SELECT query for T2:

```
SELECT
SubmissionId,
FieldName,
FieldValue
FROM
#__submission_values
WHERE
FormId = 6
AND
FieldName IN ('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6')
ORDER BY SubmissionId ASC
```

Sample data

```
T1 
DateSubmitted  FormId
2013-02-01    6
2013-02-02    6
2013-02-03    6
2013-02-04    6
2013-02-05    6
2013-02-06    6

T2 
FormId  FieldName     FieldValue   SubmissionId 
6        Field1        Value1       1 
6        Field2        Value2       2 
6        Field3        Value3       3 
6        Field4        Value4       4
6        Field5        Value5       4 
6        Field6        Value6       6
```

Comment: What is your common field in the tables?

Comment: By ...to move DateSubmitted column from T1 to T2... you mean update data it t2, create such a column in t2 and drop it in t1, or you just need a SELECT from both tables? Make it clear please.

Comment: If it is a select provide column names for both tables and desired output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to be as specific in your questions as possible and provide your table definitions, sample data, and desired output, so that we won't guess what is it really you want us to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use this?

```
UPDATE T2
SET T2.DateSubmitted=T1.DateSubmitted
WHERE T1.FormId=T2.FormId
```

Comment: Thnx! I suppose I could but prefer to avoid modifying T2 if I don't have to :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
If you just need a select that joins both tables your query might look like

```
SELECT t2.SubmissionId,
       t2.FieldName,
       t2.FieldValue,
       t1.DateSubmitted
  FROM t2 INNER JOIN 
       t1 ON t2.FormId = t1.FormId
 WHERE t2.FormId = 6 AND
       t2.FieldName IN ('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6')
 ORDER BY t2.SubmissionId
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffdce/3)

Comment: Thank you! Column DateSubmitted does not exist in T2. I prefer not to create the column so not to modify the table...unless I must and please tell me if I must :)

Comment: @Molson Please provide column names for both tables and desired output  (by specifying column names that you need in a resultset). See how other people do that in their questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/14825309/1920232

Comment: Column DateSubmitted in T1. Columns FieldName, FieldValue, SubmissionId in T2. Column FormId is in T1 and T2. I simply need to add DateSubmitted from T1 to T2 (whithout modifying table if possible) and then run the query.

Comment: Got the query to run after removing UPDATE clause. Now field3 is not displaying. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Molson Which is understandable since you use either `SELECT` or `UPDATE` not both

Comment: @Molson Since you didn't provide sample data it's not clear why  *field3 is not displaying*. But it might be because either `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause filter it out. Try to run `SELECT` without `WHERE` clause. See what happens.

Comment: Fixed missing Field3. SELECT query runs good but DateSubmitted is not displaying.

Comment: T1
| DateSubmitted | FormId |
Date 1      6
Date 2      6
Date 3       6
Date 4      6
Date 5      6
Date 6      6

T2
| FormId | FieldName | FieldValue | SubmissionId |
    6       Field1        Value1 1
    6     Field2        Value2 2
    6       Field3        Value3 3
    6     Field4        Value4 4
    6       Field5   Value5 4
    6     Field6   Value6 6

Comment: @Molson What is the rule for choosing `DateSubmitted` from T1 for every row in T2 since you don't have `SubmissionId` in T1 and all dates are different?

Comment: DateSubmitted contains the DATE when form was submitted by user. Other form submission data is in T2. I need the date to be retrieved from T1, combined with T2 and displayed.